# Capturing Black image with Flash_ON in Nexus 4 in android

Tags: camera

I am using custom camera in android.When i am capturing image with Flash_ON, the image is too dark almost black in Nexus 4 only.But it is fine on other devices.Please help me .

My code is given below :-

```
    CameraInfo cameraInfo = new CameraInfo();
    Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, cameraInfo);
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();

    Size bestPreviewSize = determineBestPreviewSize(parameters);
    Size bestPictureSize = determineBestPictureSize(parameters);
    mSize = bestPreviewSize;
    parameters.setPreviewSize(bestPreviewSize.width,.setPreviewSize(bestPreviewSize.width,  
    parameters.setPictureSize(bestPictureSize.width, bestPictureSize.height);

    if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
    } else {
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
        parameters.setSceneMode(Parameters.SCENE_MODE_AUTO);
        parameters.setFocusMode(Parameters.FOCUS_MODE_AUTO);
    }

    camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change the value of Parameter you need to set as follows

```
parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
```

Flash should turn off automatically. If it doesn't then turn off it manually in shutter callback

```
ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onShutter() {
        try {
            Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
            params.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_OFF);
            camera.setParameters(params);
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
};
```